# Browser detection in android

Tags: android, browser, browser-detection

I am trying to make an application which populates list of all the applications present on the phone.

I am unable to figure out the trait or property to classify any application which is a browser in android.

1. Any particular way to figure out if the application is a browser or not?
2. Does browser require any special permission, by which I can determine if this application is a web browser.
3. Any possibility to find it through my application?

Answer (score 0):

1) As far as i know you have access to package names of applications installed on device, which would be hard to distinguish web browsers amongst them

2) Unless you are not implementing your own browser, no.

3) As far as, i know system invokes the user's default browser.

Still it would be sweet if someone come up with a solution to find installed browsers music players, etc... that would solve your problem. Good Luck!

Comment: I appreciate your input's :)

Still looking for a accurate way to figure out that particular application is a browser , e.g dolphin,firefox,chrome is a browser etc